# Matching range without one character with regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'd like to create a regex pattern that captures everything within a selfclosing html tag in a string, it is to be used in a php preg_replace that removes all selfclosing tags (that are normally not selfclosing, i.e. div, span etc.) from a html dom string.

Here's an example. In the string:

```
'<div id="someId><div class="someClass" /></div>'
```

I would like to get the match:

```
'<div class="someClass" />'
```

But I keep getting no match at all or this match:

```
'<div id="someId><div class="someClass" />'
```

I have tried the following regex patterns and various combinations of them

A simple regex pattern with the dot wildcard and excluding ">":

```
~<div.*?[^>].*?.*?/>~
```

A negative lookahead regex:

```
~<div(?!.*?>.*?)/>~
```

A negative lookbehind regex:

```
~<div.*?(?<!>).*?/>~
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `<div class="someClass">.*?</div>`

Comment: The above was just an example, which I should have been more clear about. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parser approach instead:

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
<div id="someId">
    <div class="someClass" />
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$divs = $xpath->query("//div[@class='someClass']");
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    // do sth. useful here
}

?>
```

This sets up the `DOM` and looks for the div in question (via an xpath expression).

Comment: The above was merely an example, which I should have been more clear about. But I wasn't aware about those DOM functionalities in PHP you mention above, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I unnecessarily complicated the answer:

For my example this will yield the correct result:

```
~<div[^>]+?/>~
```

'div' can be replaced by a capture group to include additional tags if needed

Answer (score 0):

Use following regex:

```
<div[^<]*\/>
```

This regex just checks that there is no `<` inside the self-closing tag. This will be a problem if `<` is used inside the tag (eg. in a string).

To excluce `<` inside a string:

```
<div(?:[^<]*["'][^"']*["'][^<]*)\/>
```